# Looking for a way to plot angle and distance on a semi circle

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of angle data ranging from 0 to 180 degrees, along with an equal amount of distances ranging from 0 to 100 metres.

I'm looking for a way to get a semi circle (like the top half of a rose plot) where for each data point I can have a bar coming out from the centre, at the relevant angle, with the bars length corresponding to the distance.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why wont you use the regular `rose` plot with an additional line such as `ylim([0 2)` ?

Comment: Don't vandalize your post. Why would you want to do that? By vandalizing your post you risk being suspended. People have been helpful to you, why don't be helpful and keep your post for future readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might do what you want. Just convert to Cartesian and separate into cell arrays.

```
%Generate sample data
theta = pi*rand(10, 1); r = 15*rand(size(theta));

%Make (x,y) coordinates
x0 = r.*cos(theta);
y0 = r.*sin(theta);

%Convert to cell arrays, this is assuming a column vector, if it were a 1 x N row vector change the `2` to a `1` and `vertcat` to `horzcat`. 
xy = vertcat(num2cell([zeros(size(x0)), x0], 2)', num2cell([zeros(size(y0)), y0], 2)');

%Make the plot
plot(xy{:})
```

Edit:
Explaining the

```
xy = vertcat(num2cell([zeros(size(x0)), x0], 2)', num2cell([zeros(size(y0)), y0], 2)');
```

line better.

`vertcat(A,B)` is the same as `[A; B]`, just a bit neater. So it is concatenating the `x` and `y` coordinates.

`num2cell(x, 2)` converts a N x M matrix `x` into a N x 1 cell array containing 1 x M vectors. This allows for each line to have it's own cell.

By transposing then concatenating the cell arrays you end up with the x coordinates for the first line in `xy{1}` and the y coordinates in `xy{2}` and so on.

Therefore when you do the `plot(xy{:})` the argument plot sees is

```
plot(line1X, line1Y, line2X, line2Y, ...)
```

Comment: No, the same way that if I wanted to plot two different functions `x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100); plot(x, sin(x), x, cos(x))` putting it in the cell array makes Matlab see the line `xy{:}` as `plot([0;x(1)], [0;y(1)], [0;x(2)], [0;y(2)], ...)`